Cryptography Fernet prevents my windows service from starting
As per the title - here is my reproducible example (be sure to change the path to the logging file):
my_service.py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=r'C:\path\to\where\windows\service\is\service_log.txt', level=logging.DEBUG)

import os
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
import json
import winreg
import win32crypt
# the below is needed to make boto3 work properly with threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
# for the service
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
# from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


class OnePrintService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        self.running = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.running = False

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED, (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.running = True
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        while self.running:
            logging.debug("looped")
            time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(OnePrintService)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


open up a command prompt
change directory (cd C:\new\directory\) to where the script is.
run python my_script.py install
run python my_script.py start
wait a few seconds to make sure it had enough time to output a log or two
run python my_script.py stop

With the Fernet module commented out, it will run fine. With the Fernet module in, when you run python my_script.py stop it will show an error in the command prompt.
How do I fix this?
Additionally, I pip uninstall and pip install Fernet, which seems promising, but as soon as I have to repackage my custom module (which requires Fernet), it won't execute the process any longer. My custom (packaged) module require Fernet in the .toml file - worth mentioning that this custom module is different than the service.

The problem is that there were missing imports. Using the reproducible example, I wrapped the imports in a try-except and logged out the error. My code wouldn't log out the error, in fact, it said that it imported everything successfully. I then had to include those imports for the proper package.toml requirements section.
